# Mysql update shift column values

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-update

Yo guys. I have got 3 rows in my table news (image_1, image_2, image_3). Can I swap them like that? Because this part of code doesn't work.

```
mysql_query("update news 
             set image_1=image_2, 
                 image_2=image_3, 
                 image_3='' 
             where image_1=$_GET[deletephoto]");
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `image_1`?

Comment: Please post the Schema of your table (columns and some sample data if possible). It's very unlikely that this query will do what you want.

Comment: It will probably work if you put quotes around `$_GET[deletephoto]`.

Comment: Well. This mechanic works like that. I have got two tables. One for news and one for images. In images I have got id, path to images. In news I have got some content and 3 images (image_1,2,3). Now I am solving the problem when one of the images is deleted from table images (image id is in deletephoto).

Comment: So I delete on of the images with id 5 from table images. And now I want to  edit news and remove this image from news

Comment: So if it is image_1. I have to move image_2 and image_3 on -1 position. If it is image_2 id. I have to move only image_3. And if it is image_3 than I have to set image_3=""

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work."  What you are trying should work, as long as you don't reference the value of a column you already changed in the same query.  MySQL changes them left to right according to the position in the query (which is technically wrong, because you *should* be able to `SET a=b, b=a` and swap 2 columns, but in MySQL, both columns would actually end up with the original value of b, since you set a to b, then used the "new" a to set b.)